# change image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image 'view more' that when I click on more data is appended, what I want to do is change image before data is appended, I've tried multiple solution found on internet but nothig seems to work. Here is my code

```
<script language="Javascript">
     function openFromButton(lastLoadedIndex) {
      lastLoadedIndex = (typeof(lastLoadedIndex)=='undefined') ? '' : lastLoadedIndex;
     jQuery.get('liste_ti.asp?from_item='+ lastLoadedIndex +'&param='+(new                  Date()).getTime(), function(data) { 
//alert(data);

      jQuery("#liste").append(data);

       });



        }


    </script>
```

and my image

```
 <div class="lazyLoading"><a href="#"> <img src="images/view_more_arrow.png" border="0" height="6" width="11"></a> <a href="javascript:openFromButton()">view more</a></div></td>
```

Comment: what is `lastLoadedIndex`?

Comment: And this is the image I want to dispplay on click
 <div class="lazyLoading"><img src="images/loader.gif"></div></td>

Comment: do you want the image to be aplayed before the text is appended or after ?

Comment: i updated my answer now you know where to put your image if you want it tobe show before or/and after the extra text is appended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this :**

give your img an ID like this :

```
<div class="lazyLoading"><a href="#"> <img id="yourid" src="images/view_more_arrow.png" border="0" height="6" width="11"></a> <a href="javascript:openFromButton()">view more</a></div></td>
```

now change your code to this :

```
<script language="Javascript">
     function openFromButton(lastLoadedIndex) {
      lastLoadedIndex = (typeof(lastLoadedIndex)=='undefined') ? '' : lastLoadedIndex;
         //change it here if you want to put a loading  img. 
         // jQuery("#yourid").attr('src','your/loading/img/url');
 jQuery.get('liste_ti.asp?from_item='+ lastLoadedIndex +'&param='+(new                  Date()).getTime(), function(data) { 
//alert(data);

      jQuery("#liste").append(data);
       //change it here to be shown after the text is appended (loading finished ;) )
      jQuery("#yourid").attr('src','your/img/url');
       });



        }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then use `.load()` method. This will append the content after the images have  loaded.